# No route matches error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>"json"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

for:

```
http://localhost:3000/events.json
```

events controller index action:

```
# GET /events
# GET /events.json
def index
  @events = Event.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @events }
    format.html { @events }
  end
end
```

Is there something wrong in this process?

This is part of `routes.rb`:

```
resources :forums, :presentations, :partners, :literatures,
                :asset_types, :products, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files,
                :events, :venues, :halls, :webcasts, :templates, :chats

    resources :booths do
        resources :chats
    end

    authenticated :user do
        root :to => 'users#dashboard', as: :devise_root
    end

    root :to => 'visitors#home'

    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {
                                        :registrations => "registrations",
                                        :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"
                                        }

    resources :users

    devise_scope :user do
      get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    end
```

Stack trace:

```
Started GET "/events.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-17 02:15:32 +1100
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (19.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  [1m[35mUser Load (15.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUploadedFile Load (19.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "uploaded_files".* FROM "uploaded_files" WHERE "uploaded_files"."imageable_id" = $1 AND "uploaded_files"."imageable_type" = $2 ORDER BY "uploaded_files"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["imageable_id", 1], ["imageable_type", "User"]]
  [1m[35m (19.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."name" = 'admin'[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mRole Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."name" = 'admin'  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles".resource_type = 'Product' AND
 ("roles".resource_id IS NULL OR "roles".resource_id = "products".id) WHERE ("roles".name IN ('admin') AND "roles".resource_type = 'Product') AND ("roles".id IN (3) AND ((resource_id = "products".id) OR (resource_id IS NULL)))[0m
  [1m[35mEvent Load (18.0ms)[0m  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 746ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>"json"} missing required keys: [:id]:

  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:35:in `generate'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:576:in `generate'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:606:in `generate'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:642:in `url_for'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:155:in `url_for'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:209:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:178:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:249:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
  (eval):8:in `_fast_attributes'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:466:in `rescue in attributes'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:454:in `attributes'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:478:in `_serializable_hash'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:360:in `serializable_hash'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:89:in `block in _serializable_array'
  C:0:in `map'
  active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:79:in `_serializable_array'
```

Comment: What do you have in your routes file?

Comment: @Mischa `resources :events`

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: you call action :show, on your code i see :index it normal?

Comment: @Monk_Code why is it returning that action when I called `events.json`?

Comment: I don `t know but perhaps even where it is called the show.

Comment: Very strange. It *does* go to the `index` action: `Processing by EventsController#index as JSON`. After that you get `ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>"json"} missing required keys: [:id]`. Somewhere it's trying to generate a 'show' URL, which fails because of a missing key.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to use a route in your `index` view which is causing the error, for instance:

```
event_path(format: :json)
```

would produce the exact error message you are seeing. So perhaps you mean `events_path`, or you need to supply an ID for example `event_path(@event, format: :json)`.

Comment: I'm trying to return JSON for index view. I've even tried `index.js.haml` but that seems to create same error. According to it, it's somehow trying to call show when `format.json { render json: @events }` is invoked

Comment: Ah yeah, good point. Could you add your `routes.rb` to the question and also what happens when you go to `http://localhost:3000/events`?

Comment: I just added part of my `routes.rb` when I go to `http://localhost:3000/events` html is returning correctly

Comment: Put the stack trace from your log file in your question please :).

Comment: The request from your log should look like: `ActionController::RoutingError(No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>"json"} missing required keys: [:id]):
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in` for example. I think you've posted the wrong part of the trace.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45372/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-passionate-developer)

Comment: you've missed off the important lines again, it's the lines AFTER the last line you've put.